# Randomly Prompted for User Credentials

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, authentication

SharePoint 2013 - 4 server farm with 2 WFE. We recently migrated all our users to a different domain while the farm remained in it's existing domain.  We used the Move-SPUser command to migrate our users. Everything seems to be ok now but for one weird issue.

Every so often a user will be prompted for their username and password. This will be while trying to upload a document, publish a workflow or action a task. It almost never works to enter the details, if we simply try again one or two more times, it works. If we hit cancel on the prompt we get a 401 Unauthorized error.

What could be causing this issue?  What type of logging should I be doing to try and capture it as right now nothing is showing up in the logs.

Thanks!

Comment: What browsers are your users utilizing?

Comment: Chrome and I.E. (we have some applications that require I.E. still internally).  I.E. actually seems to be better than Chrome for seeing the error but the majority of the ORG uses Chrome.

Comment: Is your setup using claims authentication or NTLM?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. We use Claims Based that is NTLM.  Kerberos is not configured if that's what you meant.  But I am also no expert here so maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: I also wanted to add, I have a way of testing.  I look at a list over 5000.  Since I am an admin, I normally can see the list.  I hit refresh a bunch of times and sometimes I get the "you can't see the items due to item limit" and sometimes I see the list.  Watching the logs while doing this looks like it Auth's just fine both times.

Comment: Okay, you are now describing two different things.

Comment: claims-based authentication is NOT the same as NTLM.  If you are utilizing claims-based authentication it necessitates Kerberos.  Claims-based authentication primer: https://bit.ly/3maNkYu   Primers on Kerberos AuthN:  https://bit.ly/3BiZUJo   And another SharePoint stack exchange question:  https://bit.ly/3nvrdeQ